# I can't install anything because apt-get requires an password

Tags: linux, apt

I have a problem installing new packages on Lubuntu. I have the root password of the system. when I type some command to install or update, using `apt-get`, the terminal shows the message:

"No passwd entry for user"

I'm using the true login admin.

Can someone help me solve this problem?

Comment: Are you using `sudo`? Try typing `sudo apt-get {command}` and let us know what happens.

Comment: What does "the true login admin" mean?

Comment: the true login admin, I mean about the same default login, administrator login.

Answer (score 2):

Type (as **root** user): `apt-get install <package>`

OR as a non-root user with sudo access...

Type: `sudo apt-get install <package>`

Comment: If those don't work, please paste in your commands and the output.

Comment: Strange... now it's works, and I just type sudo apt-get install alien, to do a test.